# How can I group similar multiple items in a list in the same consecutive order

Tags: python

I'm trying to group similar items in a list in the same consecutive order, example:

```
my_list = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', red]
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
my_list = ['blue', [x2, 'red'], [x2, 'blue', 'green', 'red'], [x2, 'green', 'blue'], red]
```

I'm trying to group up to 3 similar items together - how can I do this?

I can group single consecutive items but don't know how to group multiple items.

Comment: The result you're looking for isn't syntactically valid Python (unless `x2` is defined somewhere, in which case - as what?), so it's unclear what you want. Maybe `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: What is `x2`? Do you mean `2`?

Comment: Start by thinking about how you would solve the problem by hand, step by step. For example, when you produced this output, **how did you know** that the first `'blue'` *wasn't part of a repetition? How did you decide that `'red'` is the only thing being repeated in the first group? Also, make sure you have a clear specification for the behaviour. For example, what should the result look like if every element in the input is the same?

Comment: Seemingly trivial at first glance, the more I think about this the fiendishly difficult it becomes.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes X2 can be 2 (which means grouped 2 times)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm looking at the next item in the list to see if it is the same, if not then I compare first 2 items with the next 2 items, if not then I compare the first 3 items withe next 3 items, if no match is found then I move to the second item in the list and so on

Comment: Okay, so try to write the code for that, step by step. Where do you get stuck? Because the algorithm is doing something so *custom* that requires some analysis at each point along the way, built-in tools are not going to be especially helpful; your code will need to express most if not all of the actual logic directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement this as a recursive function that handles one  repeating group at a time and calls itself for further repetitions of the same size and of larger size:

```
def groupReps(L,size=1,same=0):
    if size*2>len(L): return L      # exit when can't have repeats
    n = 1
    while L[:size]==L[size:size*2]: # remove & count repeated prefix
        L  = L[size:]
        n += 1
    if n>1:                         # replace repeated with tuple
        L[:size] = [(n,*L[:size])]
    L = L[:1] + groupReps(L[1:],size,1)       # recurse same size
    return L if same else groupReps(L,size+1) # recurse larger sizes
```

output:

```
my_list = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue',
           'green', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'red']

my_list = groupReps(my_list)

['blue', (2, 'red'), (2, 'blue', 'green', 'red'), (2, 'green', 'blue'), 'red']
```

Note that this will automatically nest meta-repetition.

For example:

```
['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 
 'green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']
```

will output

```
['blue', (3, (2, 'red'), 'blue', 'green'), 'blue', 'red', 'blue']
```

You can also do it without recursion by iterating over sizes and consuming L as you build same size groups:

```
def groupReps(L):
    L = list(L)               # ensure working on a copy of list
    size = 1
    while size*2 <= len(L):   # loop on sizes instead of recursing
        grouped = []
        while len(L)>=2*size: # consume L instead of same size recursion
            n = 1
            while L[:size]==L[size:size*2]: # remove & count repeated prefix
                L  = L[size:]
                n += 1
            if n>1:                         # replace repeated with tuple
                L[:size] = [(n,*L[:size])]
            grouped.append(L.pop(0))        # move L to grouped 
        L = grouped + L                     # combine grouped with rest of L 
        size += 1                           # larger size
    return L
```

**[EDIT] Ungrouping**

To ungroup the result and obtain the original list, you can also use a recursive function:

```
def ungroup(L):
    return [n for g in L
              for n in ( g[0]*ungroup(list(g[1:])) if isinstance(g,tuple)
                         else [g]) ]

grouped = ['blue', (3, (2, 'red'), 'blue', 'green'), 'blue', 'red', 'blue']

print(ungroup(grouped))

['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 
'green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']
```

**[EDIT2] Faster version using itertools**

here is a faster version. if uses groupby to detect sequences of items that match with the items that are *size* positions ahead.  When there are at least *size* consecutive items that match, you have a repetition and can substitute a tuple.  The non-matching and remaining items of matched sequence are simply added to the result.  Note that the first few items of an unmatched sequence will already have been processed by the previous matching sequence and need to be skipped.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def repSizes(L,size=1):
    firstPos = {n:-i for i,n in enumerate(reversed(L),1-len(L))}
    posCount = defaultdict(int)
    for i,n in enumerate(L):
        posCount[i-firstPos[n]] += 1
    if not posCount: return
    maxSize   = max( i*(c>=i) for i,c in 
                     enumerate(sorted(posCount.values(),reverse=True),1) )    
    pos       = sorted(posCount)
    minSize   = min(b-a for a,b in zip(pos,pos[1:]+pos[-1:]))
    size      = max(size,minSize)
    while size <= maxSize:
        count = sum(c+posCount.get(n+size,0) for n,c in posCount.items())
        if count >= size*2: yield size
        size += 1
```

...

```
from itertools import groupby
    
def groupReps(L, maxSize=None):
    maxSize = maxSize or len(L)//2
    iSizes = repSizes(L)
    size   = next(iSizes,None) 
    while size and size<=maxSize:  # loop on sizes    
        grouped = []
        iL   = iter(L[size:]+[None]*size) # item ahead by size
        skip = 0
        for eq,(*g,) in groupby(L,lambda n:n==next(iL)): 
            n,r =divmod(len(g),size)            # size of match
            if eq and n > 0:                    # at least one rep
                grouped.append((n+1,*g[:size])) # add tuple
                if r: grouped.extend(g[-r:])    # partial remainder
                skip = r+1 if r else size       # skip matched
            else:
                grouped.extend(g[skip:])        # unmatched sequence
                skip = 0
        if len(grouped) != len(L):
            L = grouped
            iSizes = repSizes(L) #,size)
        size = next(iSizes,None)
    return L
```

The main factor impacting performance on very large lists is the variety of sizes that need to be checked.  for a 300K item list, there could be 150K possible sizes.  To avoid the useless size checking I added a setup loop to create a short list of possible sizes based on the distances between identical items.  For a repetition of a given size to be possible there needs to be at least twice that number of instances of values at that distance.

**[EDIT3] Improved `repSizes`**

Using a generator for the sizes should allow the grouping to take effect early and thus reduce the number of possible sizes without having to compute all possible sizes..

When the list is compacted for a given size, then more (smaller) sequence sizes become possible.  So we need to perform the size analysis again. Note that It restarts at a size of 1 (instead of the current size) to allow nesting larger patterns a smaller number of times:

```
['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 
 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']

# into:

['blue', (2, (3, 'red'), (3, 'blue'))]
```

*Note that the `repSizes` function becomes the bottleneck when there are a lot of repetitions of a given value in the list. I tried a more efficient algorithms using a generator but, if you need that optimization, you should post a new question so that people smarter than me can contribute*